# vmware integrated openstack giving instance resize issue

Tags: vmware, openstack-nova, novaclient

we have deployed vmware integrated openstack in our environment. Now we face some issue in resizing instance from console as well as CLI. when we try to resize the instance its showing the task is succesfully completed, but its not reflecting on the console and no changes has been done on the instance as well.

while trying nova cli for resize-confirm, i am getting this error message.

> command used:
>        nova resize-confirm e32967b8-1091-4129-b9ed-9a592ea1b378

```
 error message:
```

> ERROR (Conflict): Cannot 'confirmResize' instance e32967b8-1091-4129-b9ed-9a592ea1b378 while it is in vm_state active (HTTP 409) (Request-ID: req-b5c499e3-46bc-43ca-9212-441c13c6b2a0)

made these entries in nova.conf file also.

```
“allow_resize_to_same_host = True
allow_migrate_to_same_host = True”
```

It would be really great if we get a hand to resolve this issue.

Thanks in Advance,
Robin